# How to get the sum of a column of numbers in c#

Tags: c#

I have a simple program to write in my c# class and I cant figure out the last part. I have to write out all even numbers from 0 - 20 in a column and then have another column of the square values and one more column of the cube values. I have got all that working. I then need the sums of each column at the end, but cant seem to figure it out.

Any help would be appreciated. My code is included below.

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Text;
 using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace COMP2614Assign01
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string formatStringHeading = "{0,5} {1, 10} {2, 10:N0}";

            Console.WriteLine(formatStringHeading
                ,"number"
                ,"square"
                ,"cube"
                 );
         Console.WriteLine(new string('-', 28));

         int e = 0;

         while (e <= 20)
         {
             int e1 = e * e;
             int e2 = e * e * e;
             Console.WriteLine(formatStringHeading
                 ,e
                 ,e1
                 ,e2);
             e += 2;
         }
         Console.WriteLine(new string('-', 28));


    }
}
```

}

Comment: Before the loop add three variables to keep the sum, sumSquared and sumCube, inside the loop add the values of e, e1, e2, outside the loop print them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int e = 0;
int eSum = 0, e1Sum = 0, e2Sum = 0;

while (e <= 20)
{
    eSum += e;
    int e1 = e * e;
    e1Sum += e1;
    int e2 = e * e * e;
    e2Sum += e2;
    Console.WriteLine(formatStringHeading
        ,e
        ,e1
        ,e2);
    e += 2;
}
Console.WriteLine(new string('-', 28));
Console.WriteLine(formatStringHeading
    ,eSum
    ,e1Sum
    ,e2Sum);
```